Was a school teacher Warren Smith fired after posting a video talking with a student about J.K. Rowling and transphobia?
On Sky News Australia, in May 2024, there is a discussion about a school teacher named Warren Smith, who had a video on-line where he is seen discussing with a student about whether or not J.K. Rowling is transphobic. This video became viral, and Elon Musk shared it on X (formerly Twitter). In a later video, Smith claims to have been fired, with the reason given that they couldn't trust him not to divulge information online. The commentators argue that the original video did not deserve such a reaction.
Searching online, there also seems to be a relatively low amount of news sources talking about this event.
Was the person who posted the video a teacher? Did the teacher get fired shortly afterwards?

@JiminyCricket. I am curious about the name of the educational institution too. I wasn't able to find information on that which makes it even more suspicious. He published this video 5 days ago claiming to have been fired: https://youtu.be/iTvz9oatUiw

Please include in the question explicit quotations of the relevant details from the video so that each individual reader doesn't have to do their own research to understand the question. (Questions are supposed to be self-contained, with links supplied only for verification purposes.)

I believe https://emerson.edu/faculty-staff-directory/warren-smith . https://briantubbs.medium.com/school-fires-critical-thinking-teacher-who-went-viral-with-harry-potter-discussion-4017f1b66d63 says "Prior to this latest development, Smith was a full-time teacher at a secondary school in Massachusetts and a part-time instructor at Emerson College. As of today (May 14, 2024), it appears he is still employed PT by Emerson." It's not super-easy to find out the name of the school (I haven't watched the video).

Ironically, an April 3 tweet https://x.com/WTSmith17/status/1775657580683010323 says "freedom of speech does not mean freedom from consequence" ...

The question AND the original video have a similar problem: Their titles belie their contents. The video itself makes it clear that the commentators (and Smith) don't know why he was fired. It is only the video title that says it was because he taught critical thinking - that is an absurd conclusion from the facts claimed, and doesn't seem notable. So, the question could be: "Was the teacher, Warren Smith, fired?" If you can find a real claim that he was fired for (for example) transphobia, you could ask "Was the given reason for his dismissal transphobia?"

Having watched a few minutes of the teacher's post firing video, he explains the reason given: "We don't trust you not to divulge information online". You have every right to not trust that this was the reason given or that the reason given wasn't the principal's true motivation, but we can't address those doubts with empirical evidence, so that would be off-topic here.

@Oddthinking Now that we know the real claimed reason for firing, this is a completely unremarkable story. There are at least a dozen ex-teachers on TikTok who were fired for making TikTok videos about students; it's a whole genre of content creator there. One brags that she loves her new job at Costco.

She seems to have been fired because she published a conversation with a student that she shouldn’t have published. I see nothing saying that the subject of the conversation mattered in that discussion.
